# Windows 7 on 2011 MBP's internal HDD, OS X on FW800 one

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I'm about to get my new 2011 MBP next week and it's coming with a 256gb internal SSD, but I was wondering if it's possible to use the disk entirely for Windows 7 (bootcamp'ed) & install Mac OS X on an external FW800 drive 'only'? Is this doable or are there any restrictions or limitations that require Mac OS X to be installed on the internal hdd? Basically my main work environment is Windows 7 but I need Mac OS X for other, fewer contracts aswell.

Comment: I don't see why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't do this up to and including Mac OS X 10.6.8 version of Boot Camp.

Do test [command line booting control](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3802) if you care about those things - but currently there is no restriction other than the Boot Camp volume must be on the internal drive. Mac OS X boots fine from other locations.